Improving performance of UniqExact in ClickHouse
I have a table with more than 500 million rows. When I perform aggregation like sum() or avg() on these rows, it's very fast. But when I use uniqExact() function on a columns with higher cardinality, it is very slow. How to speed up the performance of uniqExact function? I don't see blogs related to this.
I tried using uniq() function as suggested in the docs, but it didn't make much difference.

Probably use uniq if you can, BTW, how about performance with uniq?

@jsc0218, it didn't make much difference

Create a materialized view for uniq (avoid uniqExact - which will never be fast). Something like:
CREATE TABLE dest_table 
(
      key <data_type>,
      uniq_column_count AggregateFunction(uniq, <data_type_of_column>) 
)
ENGINE = AggregatingMergeTree 
PRIMARY KEY key;


CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW mv
TO dest_table
   AS 
   SELECT
      key,
      uniqState(column) AS uniq_column_count
   FROM source_table
   GROUP BY key;

You will need to backfill the MV with the existing data in the source table, so a one-time running of the following query:
INSERT INTO dest_table
   SELECT
      key,
      uniqState(column) AS uniq_column_count
   FROM source_table
   GROUP BY key;

And of course you will need uniqMerge to read the results:
SELECT
    key,
    uniqMerge(uniq_column_count) AS uniqCount
FROM dest_table
GROUP BY key;

Your source table now has a MV that keeps a "running" unique count of the values of whatever column you're counting. When you insert new rows into the source table, the dest_table will get updated.

Thank you for the response. I was able to solve the problem using Materialized views. I used groupUniqArray in the aggregating table. Finding uniqCount from aggregated table was faster as it has lesser no. of rows.
